# String Manupulaiton PHP

Tags: php

I have a random string set in each array index.And i want to give them a nice pattern.Better if i explain my problem in an example :
Let my array is like this :

```
                 Array
                      {
                         [0]=>A Man of with Dignity
                         [1]=>A supplier *Coming*
                         [2]=>Break the "Glasses"
                         [3]=>Broken 'law'
                      }
```

I am expecting the out up as :

```
                     Array
                        {
                              [0]=>a-man-with-dignity
                              [1]=>a-supplier-coming
                              [2]=>break-the-glasses
                              [3]=>broken-law
                        }
```

means i want to add "-" in the middle of each word and want them in lower case.And if there is any other special character that must be removed too.

Thanks for reading

Comment: What is your question? Have you coded a solution and it does not give the correct output? Furthermore, what is the output of your program?

Comment: Here's a [site](http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator) that provides a pretty detailed example for a "slug" function. Loop over each of your array items with it.

Comment: ya i was trying with preg_replace and strtolower to get the output..but can't move the * * like character out of my string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strtolower()` and `preg_replace()`:

```
$array = array("A Man of with Dignity",
               "A supplier *Coming*",
               "Break the \"Glasses\"",
               "Broken 'law'"
              );

foreach ($array as &$item) {
        $item = preg_replace('/\W/', '-', strtolower($item));
        $item = preg_replace('/-+$|^-+/', '', $item);
        $item = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $item);
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a-man-of-with-dignity
    [1] => a-supplier-coming
    [2] => break-the-glasses
    [3] => broken-law
)
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/EvCSr

Comment: for a single string it output something like this : a-supplier--coming-

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju updated the answer with an example and demo link.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to strip non-alphanumeric chars, str_replace to replace spaces with '-' and

```
function slugify( &$item ){

   $item = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', $item );
   $item = strtolower( $item );
   $item = str_replace( ' ', '-', $item );

}

array_walk( $array, 'slugify' );
```

Or look at source code such as that of wordpress and see a more complex implementation that handles stuff like multiple spaces and similar oddities

Comment: I wonder if `A Man  For All Seasons`, would that make it `a-man--for-all-seasons`?